# Caseinsenstive String Replace in Scala without regular expressions

Tags: string, scala, replace

How can I replace any occurrences of 'something' with 'someother' while searching case-insensitive? So 'SoMETHING' should also be replaced with 'someother'.

I know I can do this using regular expressions, but for performance reasons (and as I do not need any regexp features) I'm searching for a faster and convenient way in scala. Is there any in scala? I searched for a java solution but I was not able to find one...

Comment: Why do you think regexps will be slower? It is speculation, but I tend to think that such simple (from finite automata POV) regexps will be faster that filter/find operation on collectionified strings.

Comment: If you've tested regexes and they are actually too slow, you could write your own custom find/replace, processing the candidate String a Char at a time, and building the new one using StringBuilder. It'll probably be faster if you do it correctly, but there's nothing Scala-specific about it. Performance = primitives + imperative code

Comment: Just noting that if you were trying to replace a string that had a `[` or `()` in it that you'd have to also escape things in a regex, but with a "dumb" case insensitive replacement you don't need to worry about such things

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regex expressions are in general faster than using your own implementation, e.g. using a StringBuilder. As long as you stick to standard regular expressions and avoid computationally intensive features (e.g. "look behind") regular expressions are very fast.

In a test I coded, the regex replace was 20x faster than a `StringBuilder` implementation. You can find the source code in this gist:

https://gist.github.com/tmbo/7889544

I also profiled the test application and ~75% of the time the `StringBuilder` implementation needs are spend in `StringBuilder.replace`.

Comment: As you found out, StringBuilder.replace is slow for long Strings, because it has to do a System.arrayCopy on all the data after the replacement (so, in your example of a 600000 char string, you're shifting a megabyte of data around on every replacement!). However, you're still faster than regex for shorter Strings. I wrote an answer below to show what I meant by "a char at a time".

Comment: Was using this gist, a slightly modified version, and found that if the target is of size 0 seemed to cause an infinite loop. Kind of commenting here to serve as a note to myself to go and write unit tests for that gist

Answer (score 4):

I just wrote this to show that doing it manually is faster than regex... where regex takes 57 ms, this takes 34 ms. It's also fully linearly scalable for any source length.

Not super-optimized or anything, and if you're using it for real you might want to enter some range checks for bad inputs.

```
  // replace all, case insensitive
  def replace(source: String, target: String, replacement: String): String = {

    // initialize the builder to sufficient size to reduce chance of needing to grow
    val out = new StringBuilder(source.size * 2)
    // last index we need to check for match
    val lastIdx = source.length - target.length
    // simple optimization
    val targetLower = target.toLowerCase

    // check for match at given index, at char offset along target
    @tailrec
    def matches(idx: Int, offset: Int): Boolean =
      if (offset >= target.length) 
        true
      else if(targetLower.charAt(offset) == source.charAt(idx + offset).toLower)
        matches(idx, offset + 1)
      else false

    // search source and append to builder
    @tailrec
    def search(idx: Int): Unit =
      if (idx > lastIdx)
        out.append(source.substring(idx))
      else if (matches(idx, 0)) {
        out.append(replacement)
        search(idx + target.length)
      }
      else {
        out.append(source.charAt(idx))
        search(idx + 1)
      }

    search(0)
    out.toString
  }
```